# How to convert a row to a column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image] 1. List item

Row1    2  6   7
Row 2   20 5  8
Row 3   10
Row 4   45 46
How to Convert row to column like this
Row1  2
6
7
Row2. 20
5
8
Row3. 10
Row4. 45
46

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [TRANSPOSE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) function?

### SAMPLE OUTPUT

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question or not, so that I can adjust it accordingly to your issue. Also if it does answer your question, feel free to accept or upvote it so that other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Comment: For large data sets, this is not possible

Comment: I see. The answer was based on the sample set that you've provided; so just to confirm, are you looking for a way to perform this function on a large data set?

Comment: Yes, there are more than 1000 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Microsoft 365, there is a formula that might work.

- Create a single column where, for each row, the first entry is a concatenation of the first two columns with a tilde `~`, and the subsequent entries have a tilde preceding the entry
  [image]
- Then Join the rows using the pipe `|` delimiter
- Finally, use `TEXTSPLIT` with tilde as the column delimiter and pipe as the row delimiter
- In the formula below, change

  - `A2:B4` to `A2:Bn` where `n` = `last row`
  - `C2:D4` => `C2:an` where `a` = `last column` and `n` = `last row`

```
=TEXTSPLIT(
    TEXTJOIN(
        "|",
        TRUE,
        LET(
            col, TOCOL(
                HSTACK(
                    BYROW(A2:B4, LAMBDA(arr, TEXTJOIN("~", , arr))),
                    "~" & C2:D4
                )
            ),
            flt, FILTER(col, col <> "~"),
            flt
        )
    ),
    "~",
    "|"
)
```

[image]

However, with a thousand columns and multiple rows, you will likely run into the `2^15 - 1` limitation so I would suggest a Power Query solution (or VBA)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table24"]}[Content],

//set all column data types to text
    #"Changed Type" = 
        Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
            List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source),
                each {_, type nullable text})),

//Unpivot, then remove Attribute column
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//Blank duplicated names
    #"Add Shifted Name" =
        Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Removed Columns") &
            {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Columns"[Column1],1)},
            type table[Column1=text, Column2=text, ShiftedName=text]),
    #"Add Blanked Name Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Shifted Name", "Names",
        each if [ShiftedName] <> [Column1] then [Column1] else null, type text),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Blanked Name Column",{"Column1", "ShiftedName"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{"Names", "Column2"})
    
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```